# How to attach the rig and animations from mixamo to my model?

Tags: animation, rigging, mixamo

I want to take all the animations from the mixamo and apply it to my model, but so that I can edit some of the animations.
tell me how to do it, what should I use?
(if possible step by step or video)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYqJ7AyEuhc